# Datatables Not showing last record in codeigneter

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using Datatable in Codeigneter. I am facing some problem with datatable. In my database have 9 records but datatable shows me only 8 records in front end how to fix it.

Databse Records:-

```
1 user1 u1@u.com
2 user2 u1@u.com
3 user3 u1@u.com
4 user4 u1@u.com
5 user5 u1@u.com
6 user6 u1@u.com
7 user7 u1@u.com
8 user8 u1@u.com
9 user9 u1@u.com

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="userlist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    <?php 
     foreach ($user_detail as $valuee) { ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $valuee['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $valuee['email']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php  } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#userlist').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Close your table at the end `</table>'. Does your table show 9 elements without Datatable?

Comment: closed it still not showing..

Comment: There might be problem into your data because data-tables working fine in my end-

Comment: thanks man the problem in database ...